# Positioning minipages in a figure

Tags: table-of-contents, minipage, includegraphics

So despite clarifying top [t] for my minipage, my mini page keeps going to the bottom of my figure.  It even starts the minipage at the bottom of my figure and pushes the caption downwards.

How do I stop this? 
(solutions not using minipage are also fine as long as it allows me to write math and position it like an image as well as having a caption)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}  
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}[t][13cm][t]{0.3\textwidth}
       $T:=$ \# of triangles \\
       $D:=$ \# of dodecagons \\
       $T=2D$
     \end{minipage}
     \includegraphics[scale=1.1]{pic1.png}
     \caption{Caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\raisebox{\dimexpr \ht\strutbox-\height}{\includegraphics{...}}` will align the top of the image to the top of the first line (`\ht\strutbox` above the baseline).

Answer (score 2):

Your table has baseline at top of table, image at its bottom, so you need to move (one of) baselines that you will have desired align of table and figure. With use of the `adjustbox` package is simple:

For example both are aligned at top:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[demo,       % in real document remove this option 
            export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
       $T:=$ \# of triangles \\
       $D:=$ \# of dodecagons \\
       $T=2D$
     \end{minipage}
     \includegraphics[scale=1.1, valign=t]{pic1.png}
     \caption{Caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

or both are aligned with their vertical center:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[demo,       % in real document remove this option 
            export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
       $T:=$ \# of triangles \\
       $D:=$ \# of dodecagons \\
       $T=2D$
     \end{minipage}
     \includegraphics[scale=1.1, valign=c]{pic1.png}
     \caption{Caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

or both are alignedt at their bottom:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[demo,       % in real document remove this option 
            export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
       $T:=$ \# of triangles \\
       $D:=$ \# of dodecagons \\
       $T=2D$
     \end{minipage}
     \includegraphics[scale=1.1]{pic1.png}
     \caption{Caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}[t][13cm][t]{0.3\textwidth}
       $T:=$ \# of triangles \\
       $D:=$ \# of dodecagons \\
       $T=2D$
     \end{minipage}
     \vtop{\vskip0pt\hbox{%
     \includegraphics[scale=1.1]{pic1.png}}}
     \caption{Caption}
\end{figure}
```